Using a Compass to Detect Islands in the Sky
In a setting that consists of skies with hovering islands, no 'lower ground', and no unified/core magnetosphere (but no EM space hazards to worry about either), how would the utility of compasses change?
I'm thinking that if the islands (the bigger ones of which would be up to Greenland sized, maybe some coming close to Australia-sized) have the usual metal ores, the compasses would (hopefully) be useful for detecting the direction to the nearest island.
How useful would compasses be for such a purpose, in terms of scaling of their sensitivity based on island size and distance to the ship (e.g. past which thresholds of mass or distance they would no longer reliably point to an island)?

We have a very strict one question per post policy on this site. Please ask a single question ideally one where you're not asking us to brainstorm or build your world for you.

In the far field magnetic force scales with the cube of the distance rather than the square. (This is why when you pick up a fridge magnet the force drops abruptly when you pull it more than a millimeter or two from the fridge door.)

How do you get from island to island?

@JustAnotherUser By skyships, thus the navigation concern.

If they're floating in the sky, can't you just see them with your naked eyes? Navigation is tricky on the ocean because the curvature of the Earth blocks your view at more than about 10 miles. But if there were no water in the way, you could see a lot further than that. I can go outside and see a floating rock in the sky (the Moon), but I can't see China, even though it's a lot closer.

@ChristopherWells Because visibility can be limited to a couple dozen kilometres due to weather conditions.

I loathe to think what happens if, not paying attention to where they were walking while testing a new compass, a scientist were to fall off their island, given that there’s no lower ground… On a real note, you might want to rephrase as “how do I get compasses to work under these conditions”, not “how useful are compasses under these conditions”.

@controlgroup The text as of the writing of your comment was already focused on 'How useful would compasses be for such a purpose' and 'how would the utility of compasses change'.

Compasses are showing the magnetic field of a (our) planet, which has its origin in the core made from iron (supposedly).
It does not show a "way" towards the next largest "mass" (be it island or land) and is mostly unaffected by ores or metals in the ground - if there is no magnetic field in place. On our earth there is a magnetic field of course, therefore compasses are influenced.
Sidenote/Edit/Clarification: A compass in our world shows earth's magnetic field distorted by the iron/nickel/cobalt ores in the ground -- ores alone do not produce a magnetic field -- but they can form one if they are conductive and traversed by an electric current (in fact that current would produce the field and the iron/conductor will distort it/define its shape).
In a world without a magnetic field, compasses (as we know them) will not work at all.
Essentially you have three options to solve this:

Your world has some kind of magic to it that allows compasses to work like you described them.

You need some kind of central EM-field / magnetosphere which provides the field lines influencing the compass to show a "global/universal" north/south direction.

You need to rig each of your islands to have their own magnetic field by "some reason". This way a compass could show a north/south direction per island. Regions with overlapping magnetic fields could cause the compass to tune to the field lines of the neighboring island (given this one is stronger there which might be more plausible at some point in between those islands). Knowing "island sailors" might be able to interpret the strange behavior of a compass to navigate correctly between the islands.



Magnetic compasses are strongly affected by large amounts of iron ore. (And they are not tuned to anything. They just align with the local magnetic field, and do not care why that local magnetic field is aligned the way it is.)

@AlexP: changed "attuned" to "showing" but essentially it is the same thing - as you described aligning with the field lines. Only if the iron ore is magnetized it will influence a compass. It is not the presence or amount of iron ore alone that counts (and the world is said to have no global EM field).

Local concentrations of minerals definitely make magnetic compasses less reliable in some areas, which are/were often flagged on maps with warnings to that effect.  Back in my military service days before GPS was in common use it was all magnetic compass work, with warnings about particular areas and about ensuring physical separation of the compass from large objects with ferrous material (eg M60).

@KerrAvon2055 Totally agree that such phenomena are common on our earth. But that is because earth has a magnetic field and iron/ore distorts that field which in turn is reflected in the compass aligning to those distortions. But in the described world such a magnetic field is missing (according to OP), therefore iron/ore is just "mass" without any influence on compasses. Compasses just don't work at all in that world.

Added clarifications to the text.

Thank you for all the added clarifications. It seems now I should decide whether the islands have magnetised ores, and estimate how strong such static magnetic fields would be - but that is beyond the scope of the initial question.

Magnetic fields are closed
As others have said, a compass is only useful at finding islands if your islands have a magnetic field. That's fine, you can give your big islands magnetized iron or nickel cores. The problem is the orientation of the field. If the axis of the magnet is vertical, then the generated magnetic field at any point on the same plane as the island is also vertical, meaning a compass held in normal orientation would just spin freely. So if all of your islands and ships are at the same altitude, island-specific magnetic fields don't help.
This does, however give some possible story points. There are two modifications you could make.
"Surface" to take a reading
The compass is useless at the same altitude as the islands. But, if you go above or below the origin plane, the magnetic field gets some lateral component pointing toward the island. So either the ships must always travel at different altitudes, or maybe they periodically go up or down by some mechanism to take readings. Maybe some poor shmuck gets lofted up in a balloon or lowered in a basket to take the reading.
Pulsars
Rather than having the magnetic field axis vertical, make it horizontal. If the islands are stationary, your compass only points toward the island if you are on the axis. If you are 90 degrees to the axis, your compass points perpendicular to the island. But, if you also give each of the islands some spin, the compass needle would jump toward the island as the field axis goes past you, then settle into nearly perpendicular the rest of the time, with a very obvious pattern. If each of the islands' spin with a different frequency, you could identify which island(s) you are near based on your compass' frequency response, just like we use the unique frequencies of pulsars to identify them.
Moreover, if the islands are close enough together or the fields strong enough that you are within range of multiple, you can use the direction of any two islands to triangulate your absolute position.

Good point with the orientation of the field lines! (+1)

You can follow the field lines
Firstly, for a compass to work, you need a magnetic field. You cannot have one without the other. So let's give your "world" an unconventional one:
Suppose that before your floating islands were apart, they were together in a floating pangea. Still an island in the sky, but just bigger. Additionally, the core of the island is ferromagnetic. Not an active dynamo, more like a cold permanent magnet. As a magnetic dipole, there will be a north and a south. We'll say north and south are aligned longways on your continent. If you look to the horizon forwards, thats north, the horizon backwards is south.
A neat property of magnetic dipoles is that if you split them in half, you get two magnetic dipoles. This means that we can split your pangea into some continents and expect each of them to become a magnet as well.
Let's assume that the event that broke your super continent apart, left the pieces in magnetic alignment. Or, over time, all magnetic dipoles align to a shared direction. This means that all of the Islands Norths point in the same direction.
Here you could end up with a cool phenomenon. While traveling in between continents, the field lines would be say pointed North, but on the outside they would be pointed south. So your compass would point in different directions depending on your location within the floating continents.

From a practical perspective, the purpose of a compass here on Earth and a compass in your world is identical. What, realistically, is the difference between a compass laying on a beach at sea level, held in my hand at an altitude of 4100 ft, or used in an airplane at 35,000 feet? None. Compasses were (and still are) used on sailing ships. Does it tell them where land is? No. It tells them which direction they're going. Knowing where land is, is an entirely different problem.
This would suggest that in your world you need a compass combined with something that can indicate direction in the third dimension. But we kinda have that, too in the form of an altimeter, a device that indicates how high above sea level one is.
So you might be asking the wrong question. Your floating islands (or a vessel traveling between them) would be perfectly happy using the combination of a compass and altimeter for navigation. But, as was famously said in the movie The Hunt for Red October...

[Kamarov] Give me a stopwatch and a map, and I'll fly the Alps in a plane with no windows.
[Yuri] If the map is accurate enough.

Your real problem is the map or chart helping people navigate between the islands. Landmasses have the most convenient property of (usually) not moving fast enough to matter in a person's lifetime. Your floating islands, unless tethered, don't have that convenience. That means mapping tech that tells a traveler where they are and where they need to go today, because wind currents will have moved the islands by tomorrow.
Fair warning. This particular rabbit hole can go very, very deep. Before asking for help developing the details behind how your civilizations map the locations of the islands, be absolutely sure you actually need it. It's the kind of detail most authors gloss over because as cool as it might be, it's usually a distraction to the story rather than a benefit to it. Although a story-based issue that would be inappropriate to ask about here, what might be far more interesting for your story is the behavior of navigators when interacting with the map or chart. It leaves the reader with a fulfilling sense of completeness in your worldbuilding without actually building that aspect of the world and a bit of mystery that readers love for the imagination and movie directors love as it gives them latitude about representing it on screen.

Inspired by thegreatemu's answer:
IF the islands have a magnetic core and the (closed) field lines going up/down perpendicularly to the surface (strongest in the center and falling off towards the rim and beyond), the compass would not show a north/south direction but it would  point to the center of the island always.
This would even work in "3D", so you can have a "globe"/gimbal compass (instead of a disk) which always points to the center of the nearest island (IF the polarity is always "North" on the surface and "South" on the underside of an island, this would even distinguish the top/bottom if "sailing" below or in between islands).
As for the field strengths: IF you correlate island size and magnetic field strength, you can also find the "midpoint" where the compass switches pointing to the center of the nearest island by correlating the distances also.
Meaning: Same sized islands have the "midpoint" half way between them - IF they are a minimal distance away from each other/do not overlap within the landmasses - in case of circular, same sized islands on the same altitude: more than 2*radius (that is: "bounding spheres" must not overlap - if they do, the resulting magnetic fields are more complex and polarity will play a role to determine canceling out or adding up of field strengths).
IF you add a device which can measure magnetic flux (field line strengths) you can even measure the distance towards the island's center. More accurately if the strengths at the centers are known (or other interesting points, like at the rim for example) - then you could even identify some islands by their readings (only absolutely accurately at the center of each island).

The answer is a resounding "it depends," like many things in worldbuilding, but you'd have to do some work to make it work like you want.
The biggest challenge would be the sensitivity of the compass.  Compasses would need to be substantially more sensitive to be effective.  The Earth's magnetic field at the surface is in the range of 25,000 nT to 65,000 nT. It's hard to say how strong your island's perturbations are, because they are fantasy, but real life local perturbations are on the order of tens to hundreds of nT.  So the signals they provide are substantially weaker.  This means your compass will have to do a better job of isolating the signal from other sources of noise.  For example, if you are thinking of a traditional liquid-filled compass like might be used by a hiker, the eddies in the liquid will be more important than they are on Earth.

Your text is a little misleading: A more sensitive compass cannot compensate a totally absent magnetic field. The compass is a totally "passive" displaying device and cannot filter/amplify any signal/noise. I agree that your text is fitting if the magnetic field would be very (very) weak, though.

@Antares True, I was assuming there would be something for the compass to detect, based on the OP's wording.  If there's nothing, the compass would not help.

You may not need a compass at all.
The whole reason to use a compass is because we live on a spherical planet.  We can only see a couple dozen km at most in any given direction before the Earth's curvature takes things out of view, but in the world you've described there are islands floating in 3 dimensional space that can reach the size of Greenland.  These larger islands would be recognizable landmarks that can be seen with the naked eye from 10s of thousands of km away.
Moreover, these islands will be visible day or night (if you even have a day night cycle.)  The big reason compassess are used is because we can not use the stars to travel by day. But, in this setting,i f the sun is under you making it night, the sun will hit on the islands above you making them glow like the moon.  If it is day, they will be in shadow making them dark silhouettes in the sky. Because of this, you can always see them and just use a sextant to measure the angle between landmark islands telling you both where you are and what direction you are going in.
What if the islands move in relation to one another?
If this happens, then there's really no sense of direction left in your world.  "North" has very little meaning for navigating between islands if the course is always changing. In this case, the only reason to use a compass would be for intra-island travel.  But, the problem here is that even if every island had its own magnetic field, any other islands crossing nearby would distort the field making compassess unreliable; so, even if a compass would be useful if it worked, it would probably not work even if your island has a strong magnetic field.
So, your civilization will simply need to skip over the discovery of the compass and wait until the invention of radio transceivers to be able to do any sort of precise long range directional navigation.
